# MVC routing Issues(Remove controller and are name from the URLS throughout the application irrespective of areas. i:e the URL only contains action)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have two routes defined in the RouteConfig.cs file.Second one is for login and first one is the landing page after login.

1 RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute("TMCDefault", "{action}/{id}", new { controller = "TMC", action = "TMC", id = UrlParameter.Optional }).DataTokens.Add("area", "TMC"); ;
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Account", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }).DataTokens.Add("area", "Account");
```

when I run the app it tries to execute the first route in stead of the default root.But if I put the routes in reverse order it launches the login page but after validating the user the landing page gives 404 error.

the following are my AreaRegistration file routes

2 for login

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.MapRoute(
        "Account_default",
        "{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { controller = "(Account)" }
    );
```

3 for landing page

```
  context.MapRoute(
           "default_TMC",
           "{action}/{id}",
           new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new { controller = "(TMC)" }
        );
```

**The idea behind to achieve is to remove controller name and are name from the URLS through out the application irrespective of areas. that means the URL only contain action**

Answer (score 0):

> To call the Default root, you need to mention this in your
>   App_Start.RouteConfig.cs file as below

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { area="Account",controller = "Account", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces:new string[] {"YOUR PROJECT NAMESPACE"}
            );
        }
```

> As these two controllers are present in two different areas, so you
>   need to change the code of your Areas AccountAreaRegistration.cs & TMCAreaRegistration.cs file as follows

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.MapRoute(
        "Account_default",
        "Account/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { area="Account",controller = "Account",action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

> TMCRegistrationArea.cs file

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.MapRoute(
        "Account_default",
        "TMC/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { area="TMC",controller = "TMC",action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: thanks for reply.But the idea behind to achieve is to remove controller name and are name from the URLS through out the application irrespective of areas. that means the URL only contain action no area name and controller name.Your answer will work but it will not remove controller and area name from the URL.

Comment: If i am not wrong you are asking about url rewriting ?

Comment: IIS URL Rewriting will be the last option if it's not possible to achieve using mvc routing.it's

Answer (score 0):

This can be done but not in a single call like you are alluding to. you will need to register each action as a route with the appropriate action/controller/area.

Example

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Account_LogOff",
            "LogOff",
            new { action = "LogOff", controller="Account", area="Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Hope this helps anyone else wanting to do the same.